# Obtener datos no relacionados entre si

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

Estoy tratando de obtener los datos que no estén relacionados a través de una consulta entre tres tablas, pero no he logrado la proeza.

En mi caso tengo tres tablas

`Marcas`
`Categorias`
`Asignacion` (Es la tabla intercepto entre Marcas y Categorias)

La relación entre Marcas y categorias, es de muchos a muchos en este caso, debido a que una marca puede tener varias categorías o líneas de producto, o una linea de producto o categoría, puede estar en varias marcas o ser producidas por varias. Por ejemplo

Nestle, que es una marca, puede producir, galletas, chocolatinas, y Colombina, produce galletas y chocolates. Si nos fijamos bien, ambas producen galletas, pero una produce chocolate y la otra chocolatina.

Entonces, quiero saber como obtener, en el caso de seleccionar Nestle, obtener Chocolate, ya que esa no la produce, o si hay varias registradas en la base de datos, obtener todas las lineas o categorías que no tenga referenciada a esta Marca.

[image: imagen]

Comment: No me quedan claras las relaciones, `Marcas.Nombre_Marca = T_Marc_Categ.Nomb_Marca` y `T_Marc_Categ.Nomb_Linea = Categorias.Nombre_Categoria`?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho pasa que esa es la tabla intercepto, me recomendaron que use las llaves primarias y no llaves indexadas, pues una es el nombre de la marca y el otro de la categoría.

Comment: Nestlé si produce chocolate Ref. https://www.nestle.com.mx/brands/chocolates

Comment: Me parece que está no debería incluirse [tag:mysql] y cualquiera de las etiquetas de Microsoft Access en la misma ya que no son directamente intercambiables. Por lo que comentas en una de las respuestas aparentemente lo que te interesa es MS Access no no [tag:mysql] por lo que un momento retiraré esta última etiqueta. Por otro lado falta que agregues una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado.

Comment: Gracias @Rubén, tiempo sin verte por el chat

Answer (score 1):

Una forma, entiendo podría ser algo así:

```
SELECT C.Id_Categoria_Auto,
       C.Nombre_Categoria
       FROM Categorias C
       WHERE C.Nombre_Categoria NOT IN (SELECT  MC.Nomb_Linea
                                                FROM T_Marc_Categ MC
                                                INNER JOIN Marcas M
                                                   ON M.Nombre_Marca = MC.Nomb_Marca
                                                WHERE M.Nombre_Marca = 'NESTLE')
```

Comment: revisando, cualquier cosa te comento

Comment: asumo que funciona en algo que no sea access, voy a ver que puedo encontrar al respecto

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Te debería funcionar en MS Access sólo que debes usar los nombres de tablas y campos de tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Por partes. Lo primero, en tu explicación, dices "*....la relación entre Marcas y categorias, **es de muchos a muchos** en este caso, debido a que una marca puede tener varias categorías o líneas de producto, o una linea de producto o categoría, puede estar en varias marcas o ser producidas por varias*"

Esto es incorrecto. Claramente, y además aparece en tu imagen, la relación es UNO A VARIOS (1 a ∞). En otras palabras, 1 marca puede tener infinitas categorías.

Lo segundo, para solucionar tu problema, Access en su asistente de consultas tiene una opción que se llama BÚSQUEDA DE NO COINCIDENTES o algo así. En resumen, te permite sacar aquellos registros que no aparezcan en una tabla.

Aplicado a tu ejemplo, con el asistente deberías poder diseñarte una consulta que te devuelva las marcas que no produzcan chocolate.

Comment: Bueno lo pude solucionar, y debes ver bien, que la tabla del medio, es una tabla intercepto.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales Si lo pudiste solucionar, deberías publicar tu respuesta para contribuir a la comunidad de SOes.